# Логирование сайта

Tags: веб-программирование

Возник вопрос как лучше организовать логирование на сайте с большим количеством посещений. Записывать логи в файл типа CSV или же все же лучше в базу данных

Comment: Вопрос довольно общий, лучше уточнить, какой объем логов будет, как часто туда будут они писаться и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Постоянный онлайн не менее 100 человек, предельный около 2000 человек. Логироваться должно каждое действие, так что объем достаточно большой.